# Signtool returns error 0x800700C1 while trying to sign AutoCAD OEM setup.exe

Tags: autocad, sign, autocad-plugin

I have been building AutoCAD OEM based applications for years now. Just recently, I stumbled upon some freak error I have not been able to resolve.

With the AutoCAD OEM platform, there is an Installer Wizard that creates an installer for the (gargantuan) application. The application installer is started (of course) with calling the setup.exe.

With the last AutoCAD OEM versions up until AutoCAD OEM 2022, the signing of the setup.exe has been no problem at all.

Now, with the current AutoCAD OEM 2023 version, the signing of the setup.exe does not work anymore. When trying to sign the setup.exe, the error 0x800700C1 returns. This is a very generic error message, and googling after this does not bring any helpfull results.

[error message of signtool.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvAgk.png)

Before signing the setup.exe, I always use the delcert tool ([delcert-sign-strip-tool](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/delcert-sign-strip-tool.416175/)), which always works as intended.

When using this on the current setup.exe, delcert returns an error message:

[error message of delcert tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm2Sx.png)

It seems that delcert succeeded, but when trying to sign the file again, it fails again with the same error message:

[error message of signtool.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8cVZ.png)

Looking with dumpbin on the headers, I noticed that the setup.exe for AutoCAD OEM 2023 is a x64 file:

[dumpbin for setup.exe of AutoCAD OEM 2023](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwXSP.png)

Whereas the previous versions setup.exe has been an x86 file:

[dumpbin for setup.exe of AutoCAD OEM 2022 and lower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrpce.png)

This seems to be a random correlation but may be the source of this problem.

Has anybody experienced a similar problem (not neccessarily in the AutoCAD ecosystem)?

Thanks,
Jens

Answer (score -1):

**Follow these steps**

- Install CFF Explorer
- Open it with your setup.exe (produced by ACAD OEM 2023)
- Navigate to: Nt Headers > Optional Header > **Data Directories**
- Add  **00000000**  to  **Security Directory RVA** and **Security Directory Size**
- Save and Sign in

I hope it helps.